# VBS file Freezes when run from a different directory in a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have a batch file that is programmed to run a VBS file. In the VBS file, it is programmed to play `Ping.mp3` hidden(Code below). And when the batch file is run, the VBS file freezes as well as the batch file as seen from the Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

> BAT Code:

```
@echo off
cls
pushd %~dp0
Files\Ping.vbs
pause
popd
```

> VBS Code:

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Sound.URL = "Ping.mp3"
Sound.Controls.play
do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
wscript.sleep 100
loop
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
```

I checked to see if the issue was networked based, it was not.
I also checked to see if the issue was the pushd and the popd commands, it was not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see a UNC path in the title of that window, could you be hit by sandboxing/limited access rights because of an untrusted share? Have you tried copying the files to a local disk and seeing if they work then?

Comment: I tried running it on my local disk but got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the network stuff, but I replicated the "freeze" using your codes when the Ping.mp3 is in the 'File' directory, the directory where Ping.vbs is located. It played when the mp3 is in the same dir as the Batch file. It means that the "current directory" seen by the vbs is (still) the directory given by `pushd %~dp0`. So, I suggest replacing `Sound.URL = "Ping.mp3"` with `Sound.URL = "File\Ping.mp3"` if your Ping.mp3 is in the 'File' directory.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the batch, you don't have to cd to the folder.
If you do use the batch, make sure it's cscript.exe that starts the script and not wscript.exe.
Just use the full path in the URL.
If the file is not there you will get the "freeze".

It helps to show some info in the console so that you know where the script is pausing, a primitive debug..

The following works on my system.

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Wscript.echo "Media player loaded"
Sound.settings.volume = 50
Sound.URL = "C:\Users\user\vbscript\mp3\ping.mp3"
Wscript.echo "start playing"
Sound.Controls.play
while Sound.Playstate <> 1
  Wscript.echo Sound.currentmedia.duration
  Wscript.sleep 100
wend
```

Comment: Yep, that was going to be my guess too.